# How to pass tabindex to tags-input node module when using it as nested directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, node-modules, bootstrap-tags-input, ng-tags-input

I'm using tags input as nested directive in my own directive. I want to pass an arbitrary index as an attribute in my directive like this:

```
 <dp-tags dp-tabindex="3" ng-model="vm.cityModel.dpTags" load="vm.loadTagts" display-field="title"></dp-tags>
```

This will call the template of my directive which  tags input  has implemented in it. I'm also set up my directive as I put the related part 
here:

```
 scope: {
        'load': '&',
        'placeHolder': '@',
        'serverErr': '=',
        'pattern': '@',
        'displayField': '@',
        'tagTemplate':'@',
        'autoCompleteTemplate':'@',
        'dpTagLabel':'@',
        editDisabled:'@',
        dpTabindex: '='
    },
```

and the tags input  in my directive as this:

```
<tags-input type="text"
                    tabindex="{{dpTabindex}}"
                    allowed-tags-pattern="{{pattern}}"
                    on-tag-adding="checkTag($tag)"
                    display-property="{{displayField}}"
                    name="tags1"
                    class=""
                    ng-required="false"
                    ng-model="internalTag"
                    placeholder="{{placeHolder}}"
                    template="{{tagTemplate}}"
                    add-on-comma="false"
                    min-length="2"
                    ng-disabled="editDisabled"
        >
            <auto-complete source="load()($query)" template="{{autoCompleteTemplate}}" min-length="2"></auto-complete>
        </tags-input>
```

But this doesn't work where as in my other directives(templates for select/textfield) I have no problem with this method. I really appreciate it if you could help me to fix this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I juts reached to a solution!
I put a listener for keydown and then a counter to count the times I hit the *Tab key*. When the counter (`scope.indexOfTab`) becomes equal to the tabindex I set for the tags-input directive, I get the related tag to focus on in tags-input(`$('tags-input div')`), I found it by hitting inspect on the input field, then I add the focus method as bellow:

```
link(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {  
    scope.indexOfTab = 0;  
    scope.keydown = $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
        if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 9) {
             scope.indexOfTab = scope.indexOfTab + 1;
                 if (scope.indexOfTab == scope.dpTabindex) {
                     $('tags-input div').focus();
                 }
                 console.log("scope.indexOfTab: " + scope.indexOfTab);
        }
    });
}
```